# Spring / JSP and Servlets - Advanced Access Control

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jsp, access-control

I have a list of pages, round1.jsp, round2.jsp, round3.jsp, etc.

I would like to build a control panel where an admin can check the list of available round(s), and only then the user will be able to access them.

What is the best way to get this done?

I am deploying on GAE, would persisting this data in the datastore be sufficient? If yes, what sort of entity do I need to define?

Comment: Very open ended question... try asking something a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of doing this using spring security.
because it provide you role based as well as URL based authentication.